# very simple but i got lost, sorting alphabetically xml using xsl and visualize output in html

Tags: html, xml, sorting, xslt

I'm creating something like a dictionary online where users can add their words using a simple form and then they can see all the words in a page, in alphabetical order of the words, the problem is that it doesn't show it alphabetically but in the order of insertion.

I got 3 files, res.xml, which is the file with the data, tt.xsl which is supposed to sort res.xml in alphabetical order, and index.html which shows the data to the user, i would like to sort the data contained in the xml file alphabetically using the attribute 'WORD', but when i run index.html it doesn't sort it , it just shows it in the order of reading data, what's the easiest way to make it work?

Here are the 3 files

THIS IS THE HTML FILE WITH A SCRIPT I'M USING TO VISUALIZE IT

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","res.xml",false);

xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TERM");for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("WORD")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td>");

document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("LANGUAGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td>");

document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("DESCRIPTION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td></td>");

document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("EDITBY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

//------------------------------
THIS IS THE XML FILE res.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->


<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tt.xsl"?>

<LIBRARY>
<TERM>
<EDITBY>giovanni</EDITBY>
<WORD>ciao</WORD>
<LANGUAGE>Italian</LANGUAGE>
<DESCRIPTION>
it means hi
</DESCRIPTION>  
</TERM>


<TERM>
<EDITBY>giacomo</EDITBY>
<WORD>all</WORD>
<LANGUAGE>italian</LANGUAGE>
<DESCRIPTION>
significa tutto
</DESCRIPTION>  
</TERM>

</LIBRARY>
```

//----------------------------------

THIS IS THE XSL tt.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">



<xsl:for-each select="LIBRARY/TERM">
  <xsl:sort select="WORD"/>
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="LANGUAGE"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="WORD"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

RESULT, IT SHOWS THE DATA BUT NOT IN ALPHABETICAL ORDER

ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED

Comment: What is the output that you are getting? When I run the XML and XSL you've provided then it looks like it is just outputting everything. I believe I found the issue but I want to make sure I'm seeing the same thing you are.

Comment: Yes Matthew it's outputting everything, but not in alphabetical order of "WORD"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the javascript, after getting the XML, you are performing commands such as `getElementsByTagName("WORD")`. **WORD** is an element in your input XML, but your XSLT would transform your XML input **tr** and **td**. This should give you a clue that your XSLT is doing actually being called, and your XML is not being transforming. All your javascript is doing is reading the elements from the XML in the order they appear.

Now, in your XML you do have this processing instruction:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tt.xsl"?>
```

But this 'instruction' is only going to be 'processed' if the XML was access directly in the browser (i.e you type "res.xml" into the URL to display the XML). Reading the XML file with javascript will not actually pay any attention to this processing instruction. You are simply reading the contents of the file at this point, and it is up to you to write code to act on it.

It is not too hard to write javascript to perform an XSLT transformation. The main fiddliness comes from IE doing it different to Firefox and Chrome. I did a quick search on Stack Overflow, and found this question which explains how to do it

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722410/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-transform-xml-xslt
```

Here is the adaptation of the javascript provided that should work in this case

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);

xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xslt",false);

xmlhttp.send();
xsl=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var result;

// IE method
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    result = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument");
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject(xsl, result);

// Other browsers
} else {
    result = new XSLTProcessor();
    result.importStylesheet(xsl);
    result = result.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
}

var x, ser, s = '';

// IE method.
if (result.childNodes[0] && result.childNodes[0].xml) {
    for (x = 0; x < result.childNodes.length; x += 1) {
        s += result.childNodes[x].xml;
    }
// Other browsers
} else {
    ser = new XMLSerializer();
    for (x = 0; x < result.childNodes.length; x += 1) {
        s += ser.serializeToString(result.childNodes[x]);
    }
}

document.write(s);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The only thing to note here, is that it would be better to output the "table" element in your XSLT too. So, you XSLT would look something like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<table border="1">
<xsl:for-each select="LIBRARY/TERM">
  <xsl:sort select="WORD"/>
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="LANGUAGE"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="WORD"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an output element to your XSL like the below:

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

That would go right below your stylesheet tag.

That is the minimum information that you can add to the output tag. Without it, some (all?) processors won't handle the XSL at all.

As a side note, I'm not entirely sure what you are doing with your javascript but you should be able to create your entire table structure within the XSL without all of the extra scripting. But that would be the topic of a second question.

So when you run this XML

```
<LIBRARY>
  <TERM>
    <EDITBY>giovanni</EDITBY>
    <WORD>ciao</WORD>
    <LANGUAGE>Italian</LANGUAGE>
    <DESCRIPTION>
      it means hi
    </DESCRIPTION>  
  </TERM>
  <TERM>
    <EDITBY>giacomo</EDITBY>
    <WORD>all</WORD>
    <LANGUAGE>italian</LANGUAGE>
    <DESCRIPTION>
      significa tutto
    </DESCRIPTION>  
  </TERM>
</LIBRARY>
```

With this XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="LIBRARY/TERM">
      <xsl:sort select="WORD"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="LANGUAGE"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="WORD"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You get this HTML, with the information sorted by the WORD element.

```
<tr>
<td>italian</td><td>all</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Italian</td><td>ciao</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: javascript (the html file) is actually displaying the xml, i don't know hot to display it with xsl, what do i need to do? i just need a html file that displays that xml file in alphabetical order of the words "WORD", i tried that change, but when i run the html script, its the same output as before, its displaying the information in the xml without any sorting

Comment: @HartmanSargente Can you edit your question to show exactly what you are getting for your output? In testing just the XML and XSL I was able to get output sorted by the word element.

Comment: this is the output provided in the link : [link](http://thelosttruth.altervista.org/xml/test.html) , where test.html is the first file i posted, i'm getting this output resulted by the javascript i posted in the html file, i just want to find a way to show that table sorted alphabetically, i don't know how to run a xls file or how to incorporate it to a html file, so i'm just looking for whatever way to so show it sorted

Comment: on additional note: the xml i'm using in the link doesn't use the same xml i posted, but it doesn't affect the solution because it has the same structure

Comment: The XML and XSL you have shown works if you add the `output` element to it. So if you need help in running it from a script then you have need a separate question from this one. As it stands, without the script, you should have a functioning transformation. I'll update my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: thanks Matthew, i think i missunderstood xsl, and now i think i need a script to run/display it in my html page for the users to see the vocabulary, how can i do that?

Comment: @HartmanSargente I don't know how to do that. So you would need to ask a separate question for that. But I'm sure that kind of question has been asked here before so I would do a search on SO before asking a new question.