# How to create HTML from XML using XSLT and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am following this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp

I have an HTML page. I want to create the HTML using data from an XML file, and style it using XSLT, by using JavaScript to read the XML and XSLT files from the server.

HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/onload.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="displayResult()">
        <div id="example" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
var location = document.URL;
var xmlLocation = location +"myXMl.xml";

xml = loadXMLDoc(xmlLocation);
xsl = loadXMLDoc("style.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
```

XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="movie">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xml file is nothing special - as it just contains the CD's info etc.

I am confused because it looks like I am "inserting" the output of the XSLT into the "example" `div` which is already in the `body` of the `html`. But the XSLT already defines a `html`, `head` and `body` nodes. So aren't I technically putting an `<html>` node inside the `<div id="example" />`, and shouldn't that lead to incorrect html ? (nested `html` tags) ? When I look at the console in safari, the DOM looks normal (there is only one set of `html`, `head`, `body` etc. So what is going on ? Have I misunderstood how XSLT works ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use javascript to transform xml & xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722410/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-transform-xml-xslt)

Comment: Thats not the same thing. I'm not trying just trying to transform xml using xslt. I'm trying to insert the result into html.

Comment: Get the result or the part of it into a variable and then use  document.getElementById("yourContainer").innerHTML= yourPartialVariable;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not misunderstood how XSLT works. The code is putting the `html` and `body` nodes within your `div` element. It is just that the browser is probably choosing to ignore them at that point and not add them to the DOM.

So the example of W3Schools is probably very misleading. The XSLT should not really include the `html` and `body` tags. You would only really need them if you were using the `<?xml-stylesheet` processing instruction in the XML, to display XML as HTML in the browser (as shown at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp, for example)

Answer (score 0):

you can thing the html tags given in XSLT as some dummy tags, you can delete them if you don't want to use them.

Just modify the XSLT to below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="movie">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and still you get your main `html`, `head` and `body tags`.