# How to get XPath from xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html, angular

I want to populate an XML in HTML page and generate xpath when clicked on a xml node/html element. Assume I have below xml.

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="web">
   <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
   <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
   <year>2003</year>
   <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Now I want populate this xml in HTML page and when user clicks on `<bookstore>` I want to return '/bookstore', click on `<book>` should return '/bookstore/book' and click on `<title>` should return '/bookstore/book/title'. I want to achieve this using javascript or jquery or angular2. I can achieve this by hard coding the above xml in HTML page but the actual xml is very huge so trying to find some other approach where I can dynamically populate and achieve this requirement.

Comment: using XSLT may be a start - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5722617/5053002

Comment: AFAIK XML support was removed from Chrome. You'd need some 3rd-party XML library that can do the XML/XSLT parsing and processing for you.

Comment: It is not about displaying only, the main thing is to get the Xpath when clicked on particular node. If we display as .xsl/xml it is displaying as a single string, so I cannot capture the user clicked on which node. Displaying can also be achieved by appending xml in <pre lang="xml"> tag, but here also it is displayed as single string.